# What is the SQL query to show lastnames between R-Z and it must only show the first initial of the first name only

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here's my code, how do I go about making it so it only shows the first initial of the first name?

```
    SELECT *
    FROM HR.Employees E
    WHERE LEFT(E.firstname,1) BETWEEN 'R' AND 'Z'
    ORDER BY E.lastname, E.firstname
```

Comment: use the same function you are using to filter those rows in the first place?: `LEFT(E.firstname,1)`

Comment: You might want to look closer at your where predicate. Your question says lastname but your where predicate is firstname.

Answer (score 2):

As said in the comments, your predicate is wrong. I built a temp table with some junk data and the query below worked as you wanted.

```
create table #employees  (
    firstname varchar(20),
    lastname varchar(20))

insert into #employees (firstname, lastname) values ('tom', 'jones')
insert into #employees (firstname, lastname) values ('jane', 'smith')
insert into #employees (firstname, lastname) values ('bob', 'roberts')
insert into #employees (firstname, lastname) values ('jon', 'doe')

SELECT
    firstname_firstinitial = LEFT(LTRIM(firstname), 1),
    lastname
FROM #employees E
WHERE LEFT(LTRIM(lastname),1) BETWEEN 'R' AND 'Z' -- change this to lastname
ORDER BY E.lastname, E.firstname
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the [left function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/left-transact-sql) to return the first character, just as you have done in the where clause.

```
SELECT LEFT(E.firstname, 1)
FROM HR.Employees E
WHERE LEFT(E.firstname, 1) BETWEEN 'R' AND 'Z'
ORDER BY E.lastname, E.firstname
```